# How to calculate if a date is within the last 12 months in Salesforce?

Tags: date, salesforce, formula

I am looking for a Salesforce boolean formula that calculates if a Salesforce date is within the last 12 months. For example, if CloseDate was Dec. 31, 2020, it will be false on Dec. 31, 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you, you just need to create the Formula field with a checkbox value and insert this formula

```
IF(DATEVALUE(CloseDate) > DATE(YEAR(TODAY())- 1, MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())),TRUE,FALSE)
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

how about this formula? it works for me.

```
IF( AND ( ( DATEVALUE( createddate__c) > ADDMONTHS(TODAY (),-12) ), ( DATEVALUE( createddate__c) < TODAY () ) ) , true, false)
```